# Turtle onkeypress function not taking input

Tags: python, ubuntu, turtle-graphics

I was watching a video where the Turtle module was being used for making a Pong game. But the `onkeypress` function isn't taking inputs, even after clicking on the window of Pong.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

```
def paddle_a_up():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddle_a.sety = y

win.listen()
win.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "Up")
```

I pressed the up arrow and even tried other keys, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: Sorry. I found the issue. The mistake was in paddle_a.sety = y. It was a function that I had to call and put the y in it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just realized my mistake.

```
def paddle_a_up():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y += 20
    paddle_a.sety = y
```

Here, "sety" was a function, I didn't call it. Sorry..

`paddle_a.sety(y)` fixes my issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the last two lines need to go in a forever loop, like this:

```
while True:
    win.listen()
    win.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "Up")
```

Try it, I think it should work now.